# Google analytics help required

Tags: javascript, php, html, .net, google-analytics

Kindly suggest as we want to track number of visitors for a portal.

We have common code for multiple subdomains.

ie:
a.xyz.com

b.xyz.com

c.xyz.com

d.xyz.com

All of above subdomains will share same code.

we are tracking ajax calls too using _gaq.push

On analytics reports I am unable to see subdomain-wise report.

It says:

Page:
/?module=customers&action=pending_move_outs

I want to track from which subdomain how many hits to this URL.

Comment: add "window.location.hostname" along with  _gaq.push ?
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'name', window.location.hostname + "urls"]);

Answer (score 1):

You have to create different sub filters to get it achieved

profile 1: rollup that has no filters, takes everything, so that you can see data from everywhere 
profile 2: only traffic for www.sitename.com. Create a filter to include only www.sitename.com traffic. 
profile 3: only traffic for sub.sitename.com. Create a filter to include only sub.sitename.com traffic.

Visit this link [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite)